# confirm dialog accept doesn't update table

Tags: angular, primeng, angular9, primeng-table

I have a table which take its values from `tablesValue`.

```html
<p-table [value]="tablesValue">
```

I need to support "delete all change that the user can do on table". So at start I copy the `tablesValue` into `tablesValueBackup`. When the user clicks on a button, I show a dialog:

```html
<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle"></p-confirmDialog>
```

In ts, I do:

```js
    click(){
     let tablesValue=this.tablesValue;
        let tablesValueBackup=this.tablesValueBackup;
        this.confirmationService.confirm({
          message: 'Delete all change',
          accept: () => {
            //the problem is here because the table is not update
            tablesValue= tablesValueBackup;
            console.log(tablesValue);
          }
        });
    }
```

Why when I click on accept button in confirm button,  the table is not updated in UI but in `console.log` it prints the correct value?

Comment: How does p-table handles the rendering? Please give us some more information on the component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

You just confused with same variable names

```
click(){
let tablesValue=this.tablesValue;
    const tablesValueBackupLocal=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tablesValueBackup));
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Delete all change',
      accept: () => {
        //the problem is here because the table is not update
        this.tablesValue= tablesValueBackup;
        console.log(this.tablesValue);
      }
    });
}
```